# When navigating programatically using react-router ,IE throws DATACloneError

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, react-router

I am trying to navigate between components using history.push .
while navigating state is passed along with path .

In IE , it gives DATACloneError during globalHistory.pushState

```
this.props.history.push({
      pathname: `/apps/propertyDetails`,
      search: '',
      state: {
        propertyID: this.state.propertyID,
        invoiceId1: this.state.invoiceId, 
      }})
```

it works in chrome , but IE gives the DATACloneError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API):

*The state object can be anything that can be serialized. Because Firefox saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be restored after the user restarts the browser, we impose a size limit of 640k characters on the serialized representation of a state object. If you pass a state object whose serialized representation is larger than this to pushState(), the method will throw an exception. If you need more space than this, you're encouraged to use sessionStorage and/or localStorage.*

Perhaps the state you are passing in is serialized to larger than 640k. Please check the parameter values. Besides, you could try to test the following code:

```
this.props.history.push({
      pathname: `/apps/propertyDetails`,
      search: '',
      state: {
        propertyID: "<test id>",
        invoiceId1: "<test id>", 
      }})
```